# Does using Backbone's dynamically created .el couple templates with the view?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, view

I'm learning how to use Backbone in a project that I'm working on and have a question about the best practices when it comes to decoupling Views and Templates in Backbone.  In particular what is the best use of the dynamically generated `View.el` and `View.$el`.

In the documentation it says that the View.el `is created from the view's tagName, className, id and attributes properties, if specified. If not, el is an empty div.`

**Question #1:**

In setting the view's attributes, id, and className does this not highly couple the View and the template file to the point that if a designer wanted to adjust the template they would need access to the view?

For example, I have a a jQuery Mobile list where the attributes and class names dictate the look and feel of the list:

```
<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c"
class="ui-btn ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-up-c"></li>
```

If I use the tagName, attributes, and className properties of a Backbone view, then all of this would be stored in the View file and not in the template.  Is this not a bad practice or am I missing something?

**Question 2**

To avoid the above I am:

A. Not using the `View.el` or related properties (tagName, attributes, etc.) at all and instead putting it directly in the template file.

B. Compiling my template using `underscore.template()` and injecting it into the `View.$el` property by calling in my render() function:

```
View.$el.html(_.template(template, data))
```

And when it's a root view, passing a target id to the View constructor and in my render function calling:

```
$(this.target).append(View.$el.html());
```

Alternatively, if it's a view calling another view:

```
$("#target_id").append(view.render.$el.html());
```

Is this an ok approach/practice or is there some other best practice I should be using?

Comment: Why use `$(this.el)` instead of [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el)? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Because according to the backbone.js documentation this.$el is a cached jQuery object version of the dynamically generated $(this.el).  I imagine they can be used interchangeably when you are using .html() as the result is the same.  If you were using the dynamic el generation, you wouldn't want to use .html() anyway as it would overwrite the dynamically generated DOM Element.

Comment: But why add the overhead of computing something that is already cached? Each time you `$(this.el)`, you're building the jQuery wrapper but you already have `this.$el` so `$(this.el)` is a waste.

Comment: That's a good point.  Removed my edit.

Comment: Also note that view's have a [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) method for making sure that `el`, `$el`, ... are properly synced and what not so everything should be fine unless something tries to `view.el = something`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**
`el` is not really for your template (i.e. not before it is rendered) but for binding your view with the `DOM`. 
You can pass in a `selector` to your view by specify `el` when you define your view

```
var MyAwesomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#some_node',
    ...
});
```

or when you instantiate your view

```
var myView = new MyAwesomeView({
  el: '#some_other_node',
  ...
});
```

You can also pass in `$` selector like in @bentrm answer as well, both will give you pretty much the same result.

You can also not specify any `selector` at all but specify only `tagName`, `className` or `id`. Have a look at this <del>source code</del> snippet: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1092-L1106

For your example, you could have that `li` as a template and instead of have your view attach to a `li` you could have it attach to one of your `ul` or `ol`

**2)**
I think I have explained A. As for B, have a look at this awesome presentation: http://amy.palamounta.in/2013/04/12/unsuck-your-backbone/

Comment: 1) I understand that el is not really my template, it's just storing the html of my compiled template.  I am doing exactly what you said regarding attaching a subview of the `li` to a `ul` in a parent template.  This doesn't answer my question directly though, but reinforces my thoughts that to use the dynamically generated `el` HTML object by backbone and set the `tagName`, `className`, etc. properties would not allow a designer to change the classes and attributes of el purely in the template.

Comment: 2) Thanks I took a look at the presentation and it did give me some thoughts on how to improve my code!

Comment: 1) I guess that would be a yes. So, if you don't want `Backbone` to restrict how you generate your template don't use dynamically generate `el`. Simply specify `selector` for `el` to the container that you want to inject template into.

hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the template can be altered by the designer. You just inject the template into your Backbone-View by e.g. calling the template by it's ID on initialization. Then you render the view by inserting it into a parent container identified by "el" which may be a class or id.

To change the styling of the view you just have to change the template. The logic of the view and it's appearance are separated by that approach.

```
<script id="templ" type="text/html">
    <li class="fancy-styling">A designer made me.</li>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

                initialize: function (options) {
                    this.template = options.template;
                },

                render: function () {
                    var compiled = _.template(this.template);
                    this.$el.html(compiled({}));
                    return this;
                }

            }),
            view = new myView({
                el: $('#links'),
                template: $('#templ').html()
            });

        view.render();
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, but your answer doesn't answer my question with regards to using the dynamically generated `el` by backbone.

Answer (score 0):

All of the attributes can be described as functions [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/XRdN3/2/), so you can manipulate it before it's rendered:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: function() {
        return this.options.dynamicClassName + ' always-here';
    },
    id: function() {
        return this.options.dynamicId;
    },
    tagName: function() {
        return this.options.dynamicTagName;
    },
    render: function() {
        return this;
    }
});

var myView = new MyView({
    dynamicClassName: 'test',
    dynamicTagName: 'li',
    dynamicTd: 'blah'
});
```

You can also just [pass in what you want directly](http://jsfiddle.net/XRdN3/1/) without defining it in the View:

```
var myView = var myView = new MyView({
    className: 'test',
    tagName: 'li',
    id: 'blah'
});
```